# why does LedoitWolf return zeros for off-diagonal elements?

Tags: scikit-learn, covariance

```
from sklearn.covariance import EmpiricalCovariance, LedoitWolf

a = np.array([[ 0.6278, -1.1273 ],
              [ 0.2323,  0.4533  ],
              [ 0.3234, 1.5356 ],
              [1.7473 ,  -0.3113 ],
              [-0.3525 , 0.2577  ]])

Empirical_cov = EmpiricalCovariance().fit(a)
Empirical_cov.covariance_

array([[ 0.48009421, -0.23144627],
       [-0.23144627,  0.77341954]])

LedoitWolf_cov = LedoitWolf().fit(a)
LedoitWolf_cov.covariance_

array([[ 1., -0.],
       [-0.,  1.]])
```

Why is `LedoitWolf` giving me zeros for the off-diagonal elements? I have a few larger datasets in which this happens.
Is this a bug? The empirical covariance is non-zero, so shouldn't LedoitWolf also be non-zero? I read that using LedoitWolf would be slightly more accurate than empirical covariance, but what is the point if most covariance elements turn out to be zero?